# Why onClick() is not working on Chrome Browser?

Tags: jquery

I'm using onClick() method to call a function when html select option is change. It's working fine in Mozila Firefox but why it's not working on Chrome Broser ?

```
<select name="project_list" class="project_list">
    <option>--Select Project--</option>        
    <?php 
    $getProjectList = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT p_id, p_name FROM projects WHERE p_owner_id = '$logged_user_id' ");
    while($list=mysqli_fetch_array($getProjectList)){
        $list_p_id = $list['p_id'];
        $list_p_name = $list['p_name'];
      ?>
        <option onclick="showProjectDetails(<?php echo $list_p_id; ?>);"><?php echo $list_p_name; ?></option>";
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Note : This onclick() method get the id value from html option change and pass to `showProjectDetails()`

Update :

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="570">
<tr>
  <td width="142">Project</td> 
  <td><input type="text" id="project_name" name="p_name" value="<?php echo $p_name; ?>" /></td>
    <td colspan="1" align="right">
    <select name="project_list" class="project_list">
      <option>--Select Project--</option>  
      <?php 
      $getProjectList = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT p_id, p_name FROM projects WHERE p_owner_id = '$logged_user_id' ");
      while($list=mysqli_fetch_array($getProjectList)){
          $list_p_id = $list['p_id'];
          $list_p_name = $list['p_name'];
          ?>
          <option onclick="showProjectDetails(<?php echo $list_p_id; ?>);"><?php echo $list_p_name; ?></option>";
          <?php
      }
      ?> 
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="normalSearch">Normal Search</a> <br> <a href="#" class="advanceSearch">Advanced search</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>  
  <td width="142">For</td> 
  <td colspan=""><input type="text" id="project_company" name="company_name" value="<?php echo $p_c_name; ?>" /></td>
  <td></td>  
</tr>
</table>
```

**Update 2 :**

```
function showProjectDetails(e){
var id = $(e).val();
$.ajax({
type:"post",
url:"showProjectDetails.php",
data:"id="+id,
    success:function(res){        
        $('#showProjectForm').html(res);        
    }
}); 
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Have you tried wrapping the php echo in quotes?

Comment: @tymeJV no ti's not showing any error on console.

Comment: Can you show the actual generated HTML by your PHP.

Comment: the option can not receive clicks, you need to attach the event to the `select` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the function to your `select` tag rather than to your `option` tag .  Try this:

```
<select name="project_list" class="project_list" onchange="showProjectDetails(this);">
    <option>--Select Project--</option>        
    <?php
    $getProjectList = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT p_id, p_name FROM projects WHERE p_owner_id = '$logged_user_id' ");
    while ($list = mysqli_fetch_array($getProjectList)) {
        $list_p_id = $list['p_id'];
        $list_p_name = $list['p_name'];
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $list_p_id; ?>"><?php echo $list_p_name; ?></option>";
        <?php
    }
    ?> 
</select>
<script>
    function showProjectDetails(e) {
        var val = $(e).val();
        alert(val);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hey, when I change first option it;s working but when change second option i see following error in console log : `TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined
 

..."value")||(this.value=e))});if(e)return b=m.valHooks[e.type]||m.valHooks[e.nodeN...

 `

Comment: I mean second time it's not call the function.

Comment: ok let me check it out again

Comment: can you add the contents of your `showProjectDetails` function in your main question?

Comment: I added it check it.

Comment: hmm.. thats weird.. it should work. on Chrome, when you inspect your HTML elements. Are all your values from the database parsed correctly? Do all the `select` options have the correct values set?

Comment: Yes all value from db is parsed correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70862/discussion-between-codegodie-and-creativeartbd).

Comment: Really a 100% helpful person - CodeGodie

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `<option>` elements can receive clicks. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tq56jz0a/). Clicking the options doesn't make anything.

You want to watch changes on the `<select>` element:

```
$('select.project_list').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
});
```

Comment: Ya, chrome doesn't support click event on `<option>` element

Comment: I can't get the alert for testing purpose

Comment: Yet it works : http://jsfiddle.net/tq56jz0a/1/